# TypeScript error: __lib.d.ts(1235,5): Error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'buffer'

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, typescript

I'm trying to build BrowserFS ([github](https://github.com/jvilk/BrowserFS)) but if I use `grunt` command I receive this error:

```
~/nodejs/sourse/BrowserFS$ grunt
Running "main.ts" task

Running "browserify:browserfs" (browserify) task
>> TypeScript error: __lib.d.ts(1235,5): Error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'buffer'.
Warning: Error running grunt-browserify. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

It doesn't matter which  OS I'm using. I've tried typescripts for different versions.

How to avoid this error?